# Java: how to stop blank arrays position from showing null in the terminal?

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code that gets an element from the terminal with the Scanner class and adds it to a shopping cart array. It works fine, except that when I try to print the cart it'll show the unfilled positions of the array as "null". I digged over some topics here and someone sugested to create the first array with blank spaces for each of the 5 position (like `String[] test = new String[]{"","","","",""};`, but that didn't work. What should I do to "fix" this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex03 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner frutas = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] nomesFrutas = new String[5];
        System.out.println("Insira a sua lista de compras.");

        for (int i = 0; i <= nomesFrutas.length; i++) {
            nomesFrutas[i] = frutas.next();
            System.out.println("As frutas no seu carrinho são: \r\n " + Arrays.toString(nomesFrutas));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/77-doesntwork on clipboard

Comment: Intitializing with blanks does definitely work, but it seems it's not what you want, so please be more precise what the expected output would be. Doesn't work is not a sufficient problem description. What definitely won't work is your `for` loop. It will crash with an Out of Bound exception as `<=` will run to far, use `<` instead.

Comment: Hello, Mushroomator! What I meant it it'll still show the blank spaces on the printing. Like `Your shopping cart list is: [banana,  ,  ,  ]`. I wanted it to show only banana (and whatever I add after that) on the printing.

Comment: You need to maintain a count of the items added to the array.  When print, use count as part the condition in your for loop.

Comment: Your output is being determined by the operation of `Arrays.toString`. Drop it and do your own output

Comment: @Rodhis if you initialize with blanks like this `var nomesFrutas = new String[]{"","","","",""};` you will get exactly that behavior. I've run it on my system as well.

Comment: Possibly a little advanced at this stage but this will solve your problem (you will need to fix your array indexing issue too): ```System.out.println("As frutas no seu carrinho são: 
 " + Arrays.stream(nomesFrutas).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));```  You need to import ```import java.util.stream.Collectors```  and ```java.util.Objects```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it'll show the unfilled positions of the array as `null`

There's a couple ways to avoid uninitialized elements to show up.

A quick and lazy way would be to use the built-in functionality of the `Arrays` utility class. You can print a copy of the part that was populated and print it.

*By the way, there's a bug in your code: condition* `i <= nomesFrutas.length` *would produce an* `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` *during the very last iteration because* `nomesFrutas[i]` w*ould refer to an illegal index.*

That's how you can make use of the utility method [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,int)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nomesFrutas.length; i++) {
    nomesFrutas[i] = frutas.next();
    System.out.println("As frutas no seu carrinho são: \r\n "
         + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(nomesFrutas, i + 1)));
}
```

There are several drawbacks of this solution:

- a new array needs to be allocated in memory at each iteration step just in order to print non-null elements (it's a good habit to be mindful while your action require creating new objects that are immediately thrown away, especially when it can be avoided);
- as I've said it's a "lazy" way, because it doesn't require implementing things yourself, try not to overuse such ready-to-go options when you're learning.

Another approach would be to create your own method responsible for displaying a range of array elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nomesFrutas.length; i++) {
    nomesFrutas[i] = frutas.next();
    System.out.println("As frutas no seu carrinho são: \r\n ");
    display(nomesFrutas, i + 1);
}
```

```
public static void display(String[] arr, int len) {
    if (len < 1) return;
    
    System.out.print('[');
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
        if (i < len - 1) System.out.print(", ");
        else System.out.print(']');
    }
}
```

Fill free to play around with this solution and adjust it in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: Thank you very much! The first "lazy" Array method will suffice for what I need, but I thank you for pointing it out I should make my own methods for this stuff. I have files with both ways so I can study later. Thanks again!